# Can't stop / Pause Flash HTML5 Video Fallback with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, flash, video, flowplayer

I am looking to do something that should be quite simple but have not found anything online to properly address the issue.

I have an HTML5 video loading in a popup.  When the user closes the popup the video keeps playing.  Since it is a short video with controls on it I am indifferent to if it stops or pauses however I cannot find anything to make this happen.

The code is shown below:

```
<video id="myVid" height="510">
<source src="http://thisisanexample.com/mobile.mp4" type="video/mp4">
<source src="http://thisisanexample.com/mobile.ogv" type="video/ogg">

<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.1.swf" width="700" height="467">
<param name="movie" value="http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.1.swf" />
<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
<param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
<param name="flashVars" value="config={'playlist':[{'url':'http://thisisanexample.com/mobile.mp4','autoPlay':true}]}" />
<img alt="" src="" width="700" height="467" title="No video playback capabilities" />
</object>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not using HTML5 video. HTML5 videos use the `<video>` tag. What you've got there is a Flash embed.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5_video

Edit #1: The original question didn't have the video tags in place. Answering most obvious problem for the information given:

I'm guessing you're doing `$('#myVid').pause()` before hiding the lightbox. You'll need to do `$('#myVid')[0].pause()` as `pause()` is not defined in jQuery.

Edit #2: If you want to pause the Flash video (which is using Flowplayer), you need to use the Flowplayer API. http://flash.flowplayer.org/documentation/scripting.html

Comment: It is actually HTML5 video, the editor stripped out the containing video.  The code you see is the fallback that I would like to control

Comment: Right. I've updated my answer to answer the most obvious problem you might be having. Otherwise, you might need to post your Javascript to show what exactly you're trying to do. Also just to mention, you're missing a closing `</video>` tag.

Comment: I have that already and it work for HTML5 video, not for the flash fall back

Comment: The Flash fallback isn't HTML5 video so you can't use those methods on it. Looks like you're using Flowplayer, so you need to use the Flowplayer API to control it. http://flash.flowplayer.org/documentation/scripting.html